# Python: Class internal definition call

Tags: python, function, class

In my class FooBar I want to let one definition call another one. But this leads to an error that I do not understand:

```
class FooBar:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        return foo()
```

Most likely my problem has a trivial answer like calling `FooBar.foo()`. So thank you for giving me a hint.

Comment: Its an instance method, you should call using `self.foo()` .

Comment: Oh! That was even worse than I imagined. Perfect, you should have written it as answer directly! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the definition of the class, `foo()` is an instance method of `FooBar` class. To access instance methods of the same class, you need to use instances of that class. When you are inside an instance method, the first argument passed to it is the instance, generally the first argument is named `self`.

So in your case, you should call the instance method using `self`. Example:

```
self.foo()
```